# How do you disable Action Mailer in Rails 4 when running tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

I'm trying to disable Action Mailer from actually sending out emails in Rails 4 and I am wondering how I might go about doing this.  In my `config/environments/test.rb` file I have these two lines:

```
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = false
```

and I also tried to place this line in the `environment.rb` file:

```
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :test
```

as was suggested by other posts but these methods don't seem to work.

Can anyone provide me with any suggestions or advice on how to disable Action Mailer when I am running tests?

Thanks

Comment: The above has to work or it's a bug in Rails. Are you sure you use ActionMailer?

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel Yes I'm positive I have my code in the mailers directory and the class is inheriting from "ActionMailer::Base", are you sure there isn't another way to do this?

Comment: so your application is sending out emails and they get delivered to your inbox? do you actually have a mailer configuration somewhere?

Comment: @phoet The emails are being delivered to an inbox because a bunch of fake emails are being generate, and I have the mailer configured in the development.rb file, but when I run the tests it shows that the emails are being sent out.  Is this supposed to happen when running integration and unit tests?

Comment: what? i don't understand what you are saying

Comment: Jamaal it's saying or it's delivering those email? Can you please switch tests to mail you address and then come back?